# How to group application windows launched via 'ssh -X'

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell

When I launch an application locally via its `.desktop` file, windows are grouped by Gnome.

When I use an identical file, but using `ssh -X` in the `Exec` line, to launch the application on a remote machine using X11 forwarding, the application runs fine, but Gnome doesn't group the application windows at all. This is very annoying.

My two problem applications in this regard are emacs and PyCharm. There is widespread advice to set `StartupWMClass` in the `.desktop` file, but this doesn't solve the problem.

Can anyone help, please?